# Yii sorting by relation column HAS_MANY

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Business model:

One invoice can have can have multiple status (Draft, in progress, send, deleted).

In CGridView I want display invoices with last status

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'carriage-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(array(
        'completed'=>true,
        'pagination'=>true,
    )),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=> [
        array(
        'name'=>'InvoiceName',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>$model->InvoiceName,
    ),
        array(
        'name' => 'InvoiceStatus',
        'value' => $model->InvoiceStatus->Name,
    ),
    ]
)); ?>
```

In invoice model I have declared relation:

```
'status'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'InvoiceStatus', 'invoice_id'),
```

In CGridView data displayed is correct, but when I try to order by `InvoiceStatus->name`

What I get:

```
(BY ASC)
```

1. Invoice name + first status
2. Invoice name 2 + first status

`(BY DESC)`

1. Invoice name + last status
2. Invoice name 2 + last status

What I expect to get:

`(BY ASC)`

1. Invoice name + A status
2. Invoice name 2 + B status

`(BY DESC)`

1. Invoice name 2 + B status
2. Invoice name 1 + A status

That mean, that I want order all record not only status, and always display last status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to implement a "custom sort" to do this.  See http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/590/sort-and-filter-a-custom-or-composite-cgridview-column-that-may-even-contain-data-from-different-tables/ for more information.